# How to declare variables without initialization

Tags: kotlin

Would you please let me know the reason why both of

```
var name: String
var age: Int
```

have the following error message:

```
property must be initialized or abstract.
```

I would like to declare them without initialization

**Main**:

```
data class Person(val _name: String,val _age: Int) {
  var name: String
  var age: Int

  init {
    name: String = _name.capitalize()
    age: Int = _age * 10;

    println("the name is: $name")
    println("the age is: $age")
  }

  /*override fun toString(): String {
    return "$name is $age years old."
  }*/
}
```

Comment: if you really want to use a data class, doing it like https://gist.github.com/zapl/d0dbc97dc974125d3583838bd78f3085 will at least not break all contracts (like equality, hashcode, ..). Copy is an issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also says: `Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)` and that within the `init`-function.

So actually the message you showed is only one of many problems. As the `init`-function is already corrupt, the compiler can not see the assignment and therefore it marks your declaration itself as an error too.

Just omit the "type declaration" (actually it's just code that shouldn't be there ;-)) on the assignment in the `init` and it will compile:

```
data class Person(val _name: String,val _age: Int) {
  var name: String
  var age: Int

  init {
    name = _name.capitalize()
    age = _age * 10;

    println("the name is: $name")
    println("the age is: $age")
  }

  /*override fun toString(): String {
    return "$name is $age years old."
  }*/
}
```

Comment: Further, in a case like this, it's arguably cleaner to initialise the properties directly: `var name = _name.capitalize()` &c, instead of in the init block.

And I'd guess you're not going to refer to the constructor arguments again, so those don't need to be `val`s.

(And if the properties aren't going to be changed, then they could be `val`s instead of `var`s.)